# Sveltekit Actions returns garbled json

Tags: sveltekit

json returned from a Sveltekit actions is garbled. I would expect something like this:

```
{ foo: bar, foo2: bar2 }
```

But instead I get this:

```
Array({ foo: 1, foo2: 2 }, bar, bar2)
```

Which is even more annoying with nested data.

This is how I send it:

```
const response = await fetch('/api/fetch', {
  method: 'POST'
}).then((res) => {
  res.json().then((r) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(r.data))
  })
})
```

This is `api/fetch/+page.server.js`

```
export const actions = {
  default: async ({ request }) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://exterual-url-that-returns-json', {
        method: 'GET'
      }
    )
    return await response.json()
  }
}
```

I have the same problem even if the json object is not fetched from an external url, i.e. `return { foo: bar, foo2: bar2 }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSON is not garbled but serialized via [`devalue`](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/devalue) which has fewer limitations than plain `JSON.stringify`, e.g. it retains `Date`, `Set` and `Map` objects.

The JSON is supposed to be consumed by SvelteKit code which should automatically convert it correctly. [Actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) are supposed to be used with `<form>` elements and the result is passed to the page in a `form` property; to process the request asynchronously, use the [`enhance`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance) action.

If you for some reason *have to* process the data manually, use the  [`deserialize`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-custom-event-listener) from `$app/forms`.

Comment: So what do you do then when you use SvelteKit for an API meant to be consumable from other programming languages?

Comment: @Eloff: Use [`+server.js` endpoints](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server), they can return regular JSON or anything else for that matter. (Or just don't use SvelteKit for the API part; that is not its specialty.)